# Change directory where Layer Preview generates shapefiles in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver

How to change directory where GeoServer puts temp shapefiles generated for export via Layer Preview?

Currently it is putting them in .../tomcat/temp/XXX and I would like to put them to another directory lets say ./usr/myTempDir?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that GeoServer just uses the default tomcat temporary directory. According to this [ServerFault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/13523/configure-tomcat-to-use-a-different-temp-directory-for-file-uploads) you can override it by setting the Java `java.io.tmpdir` option, so start tomcat with

```
-Djava.io.tmpdir=/usr/myTempDir
```

Comment: If that is the case than other aplications that are running on the same Tomcat will be puting their temp files to that directory - not entirely what I need but there might be no other better solution. Will wait for any other suggestions for now. Thanks Ian

Comment: that's true, but why do you need to change the temp dir anyway?

Comment: Because server machine (root disc) does not have enough disk space in case there would be a few WFS requests to export layers as shape files which weight couple of GBs. And I am loooking for solutions to save these shapes into another disc.

Comment: in that case moving all the tomcat temp files to another disk would be fine.

Comment: Or you can develop/sponsor an improvement to introduce a setting allowing to put them somewhere else :-) See: https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/wiki/Successfully-requesting-and-integrating-new-features-and-improvements-in-GeoServer